# Evaluate this $\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^s-1 \over x-1}\cdot{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^s-1 \over x-1}\cdot{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^s-1 \over x-1}\cdot{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}\cdot{e^{ax}\over e^{ax}}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}-{x^s-1 \over x-1}\cdot{e^{-ax}}dx$$

Suppose $s=2$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}-{x^2-1 \over x-1}\cdot{e^{-ax}}dx$$

$(x^2-1)=(x+1)(x-1)$

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ax}}(1+x)dx$$

Integrating using by parts

$u=1+x$ $\rightarrow$ $du=dv$

$dv=e^{-ax}$ $\rightarrow$ $v=-{{e^{-ax}} \over {a}}$

$=\left.{-(1+x)e^{-ax}\over a}\right|_{0}^{\infty}-{1\over a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}dx$

$=\left.{-(1+x)e^{-ax}\over a}\right|_{0}^{\infty}+{1\over a^2}\left.e^{-ax}\right|_{0}^{\infty}$

$=-{1\over a}-{1\over a^2}$

Let $s=k$ for k is an integer $k\ge1$ ; restriction to integers for sake of easiness

The factorisation of $x^k-1$ is quite lengthy, so integrating via this method seem tedious. How can one evaluate this integral using another less effort strategy?

Comment: Read about gamma function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admitting that $s$ is a positive integer, $$\frac{x^s-1}{x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}x^k$$ So, $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^s-1 \over x-1}\cdot{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^k{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}dx$$ Now, assuming $a>0$, $$\int x^k{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}dx=-\int x^k e^{-ax}dx=\frac{1}{a^{k+1}}\Gamma (k+1,a x)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

Using bounds  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^k{1-e^{-ax} \over 1-e^{ax}}dx=-\frac{1}{a^{k+1}} \Gamma (k+1)=-\frac{k!}{a^{k+1}} $$

Comment: Imcomplete gamma function that is new to me, when I read about I might ask you some questions.

Comment: @Chinacat. For sure ! Any time you want. Cheers :-)

Comment: I forgot my manner, thank you for the answer

Comment: @Chinacat. Thank you for your good manner !!

Answer (score 3):

Getting rid of the syntactic sugar,
$$ I(s,a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s-1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{1-e^{ax}}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s-1}{x-1}e^{-ax}\,dx$$
hence the problem is equivalent to finding a Laplace transform. If $s\in\mathbb{N}^+$, since 
$$ \frac{x^s-1}{x-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} x^k $$
and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^k e^{-ax}\,dx = \frac{k!}{a^{k+1}}$, it follows that:
$$ I(s,a) = -\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\frac{k!}{a^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: I would like to see the full steps, please try not to skip steps. I know your answer is nice and tidy but for the sake of the questioner I need to fully understand the result also. Sorry if I have been too harassed on you.

Comment: @Chinacat: what steps do you think are missing?

Comment: Did you took the sum out of the integral?

Comment: @Chinacat: yes I did. With our assumptions, it is a finite sum.

Comment: I like the use of phrase "getting rid of syntactic sugar" +1.